# Why is my switch widget not sliding? I can't seem to change themes

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, switch-statement, themes

I can't seem to figure out what is preventing the switch from changing states. I know if I set isDark to true, I get my dark theme, and if I set isDark to false I get my light theme. It might be possible that flutter is interpreting isDark as constantly being false. However, I am unsure as to how to fix that if that were the case. Regardless, something is stopping the switch and I can't figure it out. Any help is appreciated thank you.

```
 import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    
    void main() {
      runApp(MyApp());
    }
    
    class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
          home: ChangeThemeButton(),
          theme: _theme,
          // theme: MyThemes.lightTheme,
          // darkTheme: MyThemes.darkTheme,
          // themeMode: ThemeMode.system,
          routes: {
            'homepage': (context) => HomePage(),
            'sign-in': (context) => SignIn(),
            'register': (context) => RegisterPage(),
          },
        );
      }
    }
    
    class ChangeThemeButton extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      _ChangeThemeButtonState createState() => _ChangeThemeButtonState();
    }
    
    
    class _ChangeThemeButtonState extends State<ChangeThemeButton> {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          body: Center(
            child: Switch(
              value: isDark,
              onChanged: (val) => {
                setState((){
                  val = isDark;
                  themeProvider(val);
                })
              },
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
    
    var _theme = (isDark == false) ? MyThemes.lightTheme : MyThemes.darkTheme;
    bool val;
    bool isDark = false;
    
    bool themeProvider (bool val) {
      switch (val) {
        case false:
          return isDark == true;
          break;
        case true:
          return isDark == false;
          break;
      }
      return null;
    }
    
    class MyThemes {
      static final lightTheme = ThemeData(
          colorScheme: ColorScheme.light(),
          iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.black),
          bottomNavigationBarTheme: BottomNavigationBarThemeData(
            unselectedItemColor: Colors.white,
            selectedItemColor: Color(0xff9D4C8F),
            showUnselectedLabels: true,
            selectedIconTheme: IconThemeData(
              color: Color(0xff9D4C8F),
            ),
            unselectedIconTheme: IconThemeData(
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
          ),
          primaryColor: Colors.deepPurpleAccent[100],
          primaryColorDark: Colors.black54,
          secondaryHeaderColor: Colors.deepPurpleAccent[50],
          scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.white,
          cardColor: Colors.deepPurpleAccent,
          cardTheme: CardTheme(elevation: 5));
    
      static final darkTheme = ThemeData(
          colorScheme: ColorScheme.dark(),
          iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.white),
          bottomNavigationBarTheme: BottomNavigationBarThemeData(
            unselectedItemColor: Colors.white38,
            selectedItemColor: Color(0xff9D4C8F),
            showUnselectedLabels: true,
            selectedIconTheme: IconThemeData(
              color: Color(0xff9D4C8F),
            ),
            unselectedIconTheme: IconThemeData(
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
          ),
          primaryColor: Colors.black,
          primaryColorDark: Colors.grey,
          secondaryHeaderColor: Colors.deepPurpleAccent[50],
          scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.white38,
          cardColor: Colors.deepPurpleAccent,
          cardTheme: CardTheme(elevation: 5)
      );
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

change `val = isDark;` to `isDark = val`, or you could remove that line and change it into the provider, because now you say that even if `val` changes, you set it right below to isDark, so nothing changes.

Comment: Changing 'val = isDark;' to 'isDark = val;' allows the switch to move again, but it still doesn't actually change the theme of the app. Somehow, isDark isn't affecting '_theme'. When I remove the line and change it to provider the switch doesn't move again.

Comment: well you actually need to pass the variable from the parent to the child, in this case pass a callback function from HomePage(Function callbackFunc), with callbackFunc : `(value) => setState((){themeProvider(value))`.